# Override to field in ActionMailer based on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm using Rails 4.2 want to override the `to` field for all ActionMailer mailers for a certain environment. In this case I want to override the to field for all mailers used in Staging. My goal is for the staging environment to deliver mail exactly the same way as production, but to dump it all into a testing inbox.

I know there are services that assist with this, but my goal is to use my production API for staging delivery as a thorough test.

I'm hoping I can use a mixin or something to reset the `to` field before the mailer fires off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what version of Rails you are using, but you might consider using the new mail interceptors to accomplish this.

Main advantage is that it doesn't clutter your ActionMailer classes directly.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails

Copying their example:

```
class SandboxEmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.to = ['sandbox@example.com']
  end
end
```

config/initializers/sandbox_email_interceptor.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(SandboxEmailInterceptor) if Rails.env.staging?
```

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2 and this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to check which environment is running and set the `to` field accordingly.  For example, a simple password reset mailer might look something like:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "support@example.com"

  def reset_password(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @url  = reset_password_users_url(token: @user.password_reset_token)

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: '[Example] Please reset your password')
  end
end
```

Now to check for the staging environment and route all of these emails to `admin@example.com`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "support@example.com"

  def reset_password(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @url  = reset_password_users_url(token: @user.password_reset_token)

    to = Rails.env.staging? ? 'admin@example.com' : @user.email
    mail(to: to, subject: '[Example] Please reset your password')
  end
end
```